# Higher order python functions and setting their attributes correctly

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I'm currently writing a function that makes and returns a new function to create polynomial expressions. I want the function to store the coefficients of the polynomial and the polynomial itself in string form. However, it doesn't seem that I can set either of the attributes without the interpreter insisting the newly created function has no such attribute.

Please see my function below

```
def poly(coefs):
"""Return a function that represents the polynomial with these coefficients.
For example, if coefs=(10, 20, 30), return the function of x that computes
'30 * x**2 + 20 * x + 10'.  Also store the coefs on the .coefs attribute of
the function, and the str of the formula on the .__name__ attribute.'"""
# your code here (I won't repeat "your code here"; there's one for each function)
  def createPoly(x):
    formulaParts = []
    power = 0
    createPoly.coefs = coefs
    for coef in coefs:
      if power == 0:
        formulaParts += [('%d') % (coef)]
      elif power == 1:
        formulaParts += [('%d * x') % (coef)]
      else:
        formulaParts += [('%d * x**%d') % (coef, power)]
      power +=1
    createPoly.__name__ = ' + '.join(formulaParts[::-1])
    createPoly.value = eval(createPoly.__name__)
    return createPoly.value

  return createPoly
```

As you can see when I set the attributes in the above code and use them there is no problem. However if I use code like the below that's when the error occurs

```
y = poly((5,10,5))
print(y.__name__)
```

It might be something REALLY simple I'm overlooking. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to set up the inner function can't be inside the inner function:

```
def poly(coefs):
    def createPoly(x):
        createPoly.value = eval(createPoly.__name__)
        return createPoly.value

    formulaParts = []

    power = 0

    for coef in coefs:
        if power == 0:
            formulaParts += [('%d') % (coef)]
        elif power == 1:
            formulaParts += [('%d * x') % (coef)]
        else:
            formulaParts += [('%d * x**%d') % (coef, power)]
        power += 1
    createPoly.__name__ = ' + '.join(formulaParts[::-1])
    createPoly.coefs = coefs
    return createPoly
```